# PyQt5 Unable to repaint QLabel's Text

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am trying to update the QLabel to reflect log changes but it will not repaint. I have tried multiple ways without success, a few are still listed in the code. The value of the log_text Label changes, it gets printed to terminal but never into the GUI. (The Grey Area is bound to the function to change the text)

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QDesktopWidget,
                             QLabel, QAbstractButton, QStackedWidget, QFrame, QTableWidget,)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.center()

        self.setGeometry(500, 200, 1400, 800)

        layout1 = QHBoxLayout()
        layout2 = QVBoxLayout()
        layout3 = QVBoxLayout()
        layouts = QHBoxLayout()

        layout1.setSpacing(0)
        layout2.setSpacing(0)
        layout3.setSpacing(0)
        layouts.setSpacing(0)

        layout1.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layouts.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout1)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.frameR = QFrame()
        self.frameR.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frameR.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(27, 29, 35); border: 0px solid black")
        self.frameR.setFixedWidth(71)
        self.frameR.setFixedHeight(71)
        layout2.addWidget(self.frameR)

        resize_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.frameR.setLayout(resize_layout)

        button5 = PicButtonF(QtGui.QPixmap("validationN.png"), QtGui.QPixmap("validationH.png"),
                             QtGui.QPixmap("validationC.png"))
        button5.clicked.connect(self.widget4)
        layout2.addWidget(button5)

        spacer_m = QFrame()
        spacer_m.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        spacer_m.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(27, 29, 35); border: 0px solid black")
        spacer_m.setFixedWidth(71)
        layout2.addWidget(spacer_m)

        layout1.addLayout(layout2)

        label_title = QLabel("  PG - Programme De Gestion")
        label_title.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(37, 39, 44); color: white')
        layouts.addWidget(label_title)

        spacer_m = QFrame()
        spacer_m.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        spacer_m.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(37, 39, 44); border: 0px solid black")
        spacer_m.setFixedHeight(45)
        layouts.addWidget(spacer_m)

        top3 = PicButtonF(QtGui.QPixmap("closeN.png"), QtGui.QPixmap("closeH.png"),
                          QtGui.QPixmap("closeH.png"))
        top3.clicked.connect(self.closeapp)
        top3.setFixedWidth(45)
        top3.setFixedHeight(45)
        layouts.addWidget(top3)

        layout3.addLayout(layouts)

        self.frameS = QFrame()
        self.frameS.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frameS.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(38, 41, 50); border: 0px solid black")
        self.frameS.setFixedHeight(24)
        layout3.addWidget(self.frameS)

        self.layoutS = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layoutS.setSpacing(0)
        self.layoutS.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        self.frameS.setLayout(self.layoutS)

        self.log_text = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text That Must Change')
        self.log_text.setStyleSheet('color: white')
        self.layoutS.addWidget(self.log_text)

        self.stackedWidget = QStackedWidget()
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(Validation())

        self.frameC = QFrame()
        self.layoutC = QHBoxLayout()
        self.frameC.setLayout(self.layoutC)
        self.layoutC.setSpacing(0)
        self.layoutC.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layoutC.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        layout3.addWidget(self.frameC)

        frame5 = QFrame()
        frame5.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        frame5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(37, 39, 44); border: 0px solid black")
        frame5.setFixedHeight(25)
        layout3.addWidget(frame5)

        credit_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        frame5.setLayout(credit_layout)

        layout1.addLayout(layout3)

        self.oldPos = self.pos()

    def logging(self, text):
        print(str('Testing - Text Passed Through Function: ') + str(text))
        print(str('Testing - Text Currently Before Function: ') + str(self.log_text.text()))
        self.log_text.setText(str('New Text From Logging Function'))
        self.log_text.hide()
        self.log_text.show()
        self.log_text.repaint()
        self.log_text.update()
        QtWidgets.qApp.processEvents()
        print(str('Testing - Text Set After Function: ') + str(self.log_text.text()))

    def widget4(self):
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(4)

    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def closeapp(self):
            self.close()

class Validation(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.header = ['CLIENT', 'TYPE']

        header_count = len(self.header)

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(header_count)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(40)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.header)

        layout_tw = QVBoxLayout()
        layout_th = QHBoxLayout()

        frame1 = QFrame()
        frame1.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        frame1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(144, 149, 160); border: 0px solid black")
        frame1.setFixedHeight(50)
        frame1.setFixedWidth(122)

        frame1l = QHBoxLayout()
        frame1l.setSpacing(0)
        frame1l.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        frame1.setLayout(frame1l)

        frame1b = PicButtonF(QtGui.QPixmap("query_all.png"), QtGui.QPixmap("query_all.png"),
                             QtGui.QPixmap("query_all.png"))
        frame1b.clicked.connect(self.validation_query)
        frame1l.addWidget(frame1b)

        frame_fill = QFrame()
        frame_fill.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        frame_fill.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(44, 49, 60); border: 0px solid black")
        frame_fill.setFixedHeight(50)

        layout_th.addWidget(frame1)
        layout_th.addWidget(frame_fill)
        layout_tw.addLayout(layout_th)
        layout_tw.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

        layout_tw.setSpacing(0)
        layout_tw.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.setLayout(layout_tw)

    def validation_query(self):
        MainWindow().logging('New Text From The Query Function')

class PicButtonF(QAbstractButton):
    def __init__(self, pixmap, pixmap_hover, pixmap_pressed, parent=None):
        super(PicButtonF, self).__init__(parent)
        self.pixmap = pixmap
        self.pixmap_hover = pixmap_hover
        self.pixmap_pressed = pixmap_pressed

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        pix = self.pixmap_hover if self.underMouse() else self.pixmap
        if self.isDown():
            pix = self.pixmap_pressed

        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(event.rect(), pix)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.update()

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.update()

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(71, 71)

class PicButton(QAbstractButton):
    def __init__(self, pixmap, parent=None):
        super(PicButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.pixmap = pixmap

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(event.rect(), self.pixmap)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.pixmap.size()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Do note that Qt is usually straightforward in updating its widgets, and besides some possible (but pretty rare) bugs or wrong usage of threading, if an object doesn't update correctly *at all* the problem is usually somewhere else: bottom line, if a label doesn't update after a `setText()`, calling `hide()`, `show()`, `repaint()`, `update()` and `processEvents()` is completely useless and add unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not changing the label of the existing window, you are creating a new window everytime:

```
    def validation_query(self):
        MainWindow().logging('New Text From The Query Function')
```

That line creates a new instance of `MainWindow` and calls *that* instance's `logging` function, then the new instance is immediately deleted (garbage collected) because no reference to it was ever created. Even if a reference (local or as an instance attribute) were created, that's clearly not the right approach.

To correctly change the label of the *existing* window, you should use a custom signal and connect it to the `validation_query` function. In order to do that you also cannot just add the widget to the stacked layout, as you need the reference to connect the new signal.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        validator = Validation()
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(validator)
        validator.validateResult.connect(self.logging)
        # ...
 
class Validation(QWidget):
    validateResult = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    # ...
    def validation_query(self):
        self.validateResult.emit('New Text From The Query Function')
```

I recommend you to read more about [classes and instances](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: I understand how to do the signal and slot in the same class, but I really don't understand how to make this work in this case, even with your information. I have been looking and reading without success. Is it possible to have an example of something functional?

Comment: Have you tried to edit your code with my additions and modifications?

Comment: I had tried but had made a mistake, which I just found. Thank you so very much.

Comment: The text does only update once the entire query is over, and update() doesn't help it, is that because of limitations or because I should be using threading?

Comment: @FrancisDesjardins what query?

Comment: The validation widget is actually a TableWidget with queries attached, sorry. What I mean is, it launches a series of SQL queries upon a button push, which fills the TableWidget. However, the label only updates after all of the queries are finished. Is there a way to have that update multiple times as it processes because it is a limitation or should I be using threading not to jam the queue?

Comment: In that specific case, assuming that the query should happen without any possible interaction from the user, you can ensure that the label is updated after each `setText()` by adding `QtWidgets.qApp.processEvents()`, but if the query is a longer process it's probably better to use a QThread with a custom signal that is emitted each time a new reply is received from the query. Note that this is very important: you cannot *directly* access any UI element from a thread, and in order to do that using signals (so, a QThread) is mandatory.

Comment: Thank you, you're the best!